# How do you identify a website's form-type?

Tags: http

How do you know which attack method to use when using software like thc hydra, brutus, etc?
e.g. `http-get`, `https-get`, `http-form-get`, `http-form-post`, etc?

For example, for sites like Yahoo, Gmail, and Hotmail it's `POP3`.

In this question, for example, the poster says he:

> - pinged the website and obtained the IP address of 209.23.201.55
> - identified the form type as a `https-form-post`

My question is how you do the second step, so you know which attack method to use?

Comment: In future, please do not cross post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View the page HTML source and locate the `form` tag.

Look for the action and method.

e.g. on `www.facebook.com` the source shows

```
<form id="login_form" action="https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1" method="post"
```

Here you can see that it is a `https` form and that the method is `POST`.

If there is no action then the default is `GET`.

How these correspond with the terminology in the individual tools will differ, but learning the different [HTTP methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) will be useful in order to attack them.

Comment: WOW!  Thank you SilverlightFox!  such great and clear directions.  much appreciated!!

Comment: just one more doubt, @SilverlightFox.  I got a bit confused with the last thing you said "How these correspond with the terminology in the individual tools will differ"  - - - - - in the example you provided, wouldnt the attack method simply be https-post ?

Comment: @thisisjnd Probably, but I wouldn't be able to tell you off the top of my head what the difference would be between `http-form-get` and `http-get` because these are technically the same to the server, but might differ in how the tools treat them.

Comment: ah ok.  and to edit my last comment, it would be https-form-post since https-post doesnt exist :P